# related_name doesn't work in Django about some different objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have trouble about calling related models.
my models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_model = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    product_url = models.SlugField(max_length=200, default='')
    product_category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default='',
        null=True,
        related_name="products",
    )
    product_subcategory = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default='',
        null=True,
        related_name="products",
    )
    description = tinymce_models.HTMLField(verbose_name="text")
    product_img = models.ImageField(upload_to="product_imgs/" ,default='')

class Stock(models.Model):
    ONE = '1'
    TWO = '2'
    FREE = 'free'
    PRODUCT_SIZES = [
        (ONE, '1'),
        (TWO, '2'),
        (FREE, 'free'),
    ]
    size = models.CharField(max_length=60,default=" ", choices=PRODUCT_SIZES)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="pro")
```

each product can has 3 stock object with different sizes, I want show a product quantity in stock with all sizes, for example (size1 has 10, size2 has 10, sizefree has 10, I want show 30)

my views:

```
def products(request):
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        products = Product.objects.all()
        ctx = {'products':products}
        return render(request, 'staff/products_list.html',ctx)       
    else:
        return redirect('/staff')
```

and my html

```
                {% for product in products %}
                  <td class="text-info">
                    {% for product in product.pro.quantity.all %}
                      {{product}}
                    {% endfor %}
                  </td>
                {% endfor %}
```

how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I'm not following what the `.pro.` does in your template.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem its related_name in stock.product

Comment: @MehranBahrami `product.pro` is the _related manager_ writing `product.pro.quantity` doesn't make much sense there...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I made change in that, please check it again

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I made change in that, please check it again

Comment: @MehranBahrami don't change the question so completely that others _answers_ look out of place. With your previous edit it looked like my answer just repeated your code. I have rolled it back you may edit, but add it in _addition_ to your code and indicate that it is what you tried from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `related_name="pro"` this means `pro` is a "*Related Manager*". Hence writing `product.pro.quantity` does not make any sense. Instead you want to write something like `product.pro.all` and *loop* over it to get the related instances:

```
{% for product in products %}
    <td class="text-info">
        {% for stock in product.pro.all %}
            {{ stock.quantity }}
        {% endfor %}
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: Furthermore `pro` does not make much sense as the related name here, even the default `stock_set` was a better related name
> here. Consider changing the related name to something more
> descriptive, example: `stocks`.

Comment: doesn't show anything again, unfortunately

Comment: @MehranBahrami you weren't meant to remove your outer loop if you did that, check my edit...

Comment: I forget to say at the first that this part exists in a loop, because its product list